# Change data template when the user selects it

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have two datatemplates. One is the default and the other one is for when the user selects this item. I need to give the selected item double width and height of the normal template. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not difficult, but it is not solved by swapping the data template. Instead, it is accomplished by using Visual States in XAML. A Visual State allows you to create multiple "views" of your XAML (for example, what it looks like when it is selected and when it is not selected) and to switch between those easily. Swapping data templates is a big deal, Mostafa, and can result in your UI flickering because the underlying subsystem has to re-render so many parts of the visual tree.

If you want to learn more about the Visual States, you might read over the blog article I wrote on the same subject.

> http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/11/windows-81-how-to-use-visual-states-in.html

The only problem now is to figure out how to trigger the visual state when the item in a gridview or listview is selected. First, you should know that IsSelected is a property on the gridviewitem or listviewitem control that houses your item. However, it's tricky to reach that property and the most common approach is to sub-class your gridview/listview and override PrepareContainerForItemOverride and set the binding in code-behind.

Like this:

```
class MyModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

class MyList : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var model = item as MyModel;
        var listViewItem = element as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem;

        var binding = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding
        {
            Source = model,
            Mode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(model.IsSelected)),
        };
        listViewItem.SetBinding(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Best of luck!